# Getting null after migrating android X androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have added android X in xml

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.notebook_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.notebook_search);      
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);    
    }
```

From menu

```
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item
        android:id="@+id/notebook_search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/tab_notebook_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/search"/>
        </menu>
```

Error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)'
>   on a null object reference

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Be sure to show the full error message. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this for some tips.

Comment: menu.xml file 
    
android:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"

Java class
searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();//getting null here

Error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)' on a null object reference

Comment: Did you read the links I provided?

Answer (score 2):

Use `app:actionViewClass` instead of `android:actionViewClass` in your menu layout. That's the problem. Change like below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/notebook_search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/tab_notebook_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/search"/>
</menu>
```

Beside this probably your refactor not correctly done. Please Try **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** and press **DoRefactor**

Comment: I have added both but still i am getting null pointer exception
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;

android:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"

Comment: Still facing problem? please post your **onCreateOptionMenu** code and menu layout

Comment: I have added full detail.Please check and let me know if have any solution.Thanks

Comment: use `app:actionViewClass`

Comment: And to use AndroidX you should follow the proper refactor method. Please do that: Try **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** and press DoRefactor

Comment: I have added app:actionViewClass this you can see in xml file.I had done refactor using android studio.It is not working.

Comment: Your xml contains **android** tag not **app**

Comment: Both **showAsAction** and **actionViewClass** should use `app`

Comment: I have added app also, still it is crashing.

Comment: @KalpanaSahu, Please copy-paste my code and try. Still your xml code is wrong

Comment: I have tried this in my own and found problem with **android** tag which is easily producible. I don't know what's going on in your side

Comment: Okay let me try this.

Comment: Then I am really sorry to say that I can't help you.

Comment: Found solution.Thanks.

Comment: What's the solution?

Comment: I have extend with appcombatactivity instead of fragmentActivity ,changed theme and xml. Then it is working fine.Thanks